How to Query Multiple Media Items by MyAnimeList IDs Using Anilist's GraphQL API?
I’m working with a Anilist's GraphQL API where the Media query supports fetching media by a single ID. The schema for the Media query looks like this:
query Media($idMal: Int!) {
  Media(idMal: $idMal) {
    ...media
  }
}

// idMal = [21, 166531]

However, I need to fetch multiple media items at once using an array of MyAnimeList (MAL) IDs. The API does not provide a query that allows fetching multiple items by an array of IDs in a single request.
I expected to efficiently fetch multiple media items using a single request or a more streamlined approach than making multiple separate requests.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Ok, you just have to use the Page.
Here’s an example query that demonstrates how to use idMal_in to fetch media items by an array of MAL IDs:
  Page {
    media(idMal_in: $idMal, type: ANIME) {
      id
      idMal
      title {
        romaji
        english
        native
      }
      description
      episodes
      status
      coverImage {
        large
      }
    }
  }
}

Example Variables:
{
  "idMal": [21, 166531, 133845]
}

